# Search bar in tableView with 4 labels

Tags: uitableview

I have `TableViewController` with named class : `messageTableViewController` AND custom `TableViewcell` on the tableViewController but with it's own class named : `messageTableViewCell`. (in the same storyboard ) 
The `messageTableViewCell` contains 4 labels named : nom, titre, resume and date.

I want to implement a search bar in messageTableViewController. For this, and dragged a SearchBarandSearchDisplayController on top of messageTableViewController. and my code was :

In .h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *unreadmessagesArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *results;
```

In .m

```
- (NSMutableArray *)results
{
    if (!_results) {
        _results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return _results;
}


- (void)searchThroughData
{
    self.results = nil;

    NSPredicate *resultsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchBar.text];
    self.results = [[self.unreadmessagesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultsPredicate] mutableCopy];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self searchThroughData];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        if(self.unreadmessagesArray == nil)
            return 0;

        return [self.unreadmessagesArray count];
    } else {
        [self searchThroughData];
        return self.results.count;
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Configure Cell

 messageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[messageTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    NSDictionary *reloadedMessage = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.nom.text = [reloadedMessage valueForKey:@"sentBy"];
    cell.titre.text = [reloadedMessage valueForKey:@"messageThreadTitle"];
    cell.resume.text = [reloadedMessage valueForKey:@"messageBody"];
    cell.date.text = [reloadedMessage valueForKey:@"sentOn"];
} else {


    NSDictionary *currentMessage = [self.unreadmessagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.nom.text = [currentMessage valueForKey:@"sentBy"];
    cell.titre.text = [currentMessage valueForKey:@"messageThreadTitle"];
    cell.resume.text = [currentMessage valueForKey:@"messageBody"];
    cell.date.text = [currentMessage valueForKey:@"sentOn"];

    }
return cell;

}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}



-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailMessage" sender:self];
    }

}
```

When i do the search, nothing is displaying ! 
Any idea of the mistake ? 
Thanks

Comment: It show your data just without searching? Or never show data? Because i dont see any cellIdentifier there so that is why i am asking.

Comment: I found the mistake, thank you

Comment: I identified the cellidentifier above in my program as static string , i didn't show it hère. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem ! 
I didn't anderstand what NSPredicte does ... 
I changed SELF by something in my data, and it works ... 
So, if I base my search on the name of sender of de message in my app, I just have to change SELF by NAME. 
Thanks anyway